# Query to retrieve every subdocument alone without passing parent id using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here i like to explain my problem.
How can i write a mongoose query to retrieve every subdocument from JSON without passing parent_id.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56a320003fe17cc7363dd0d7",
    "name": "Leanna Jacobson",
    "gender": "female",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Riley Case"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Herman Carter"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pacheco Woodard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56a3200001501cfa1ea2641d",
    "name": "Juliana Bonner",
    "gender": "female",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Keller Woodward"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Fern Knight"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cain Richards"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56a3200006864c78ecb1aeed",
    "name": "Gena Stark",
    "gender": "female",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Kate Franco"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Araceli Mcclure"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Molly Nelson"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56a320006d868155161038b6",
    "name": "Eve Gonzalez",
    "gender": "female",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Pam Lang"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Christy Marks"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Donovan Warren"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56a3200066b94852f5680568",
    "name": "Coleman Wooten",
    "gender": "male",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Roberta Olson"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Roseann Reid"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kerri Russell"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here i need to retrieve every friends details from the subdocument array friends for every parent.

so how can i write query for this?????

Comment: Find the document, extract the subdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the name of your schema is `Person`, try this one.

```
//find all document, only select `friends` field from every document
Person.find({}, 'friends', function (err, friends) {
    // the return friends is the [[friends], [friends], ...]
});
```